# Lua 5.3 overriding the ~ (__bnot) operator for integer values using debug.setmetatable

Tags: lua, operator-overloading

This example

```
debug.setmetatable(0,
{
    __bnot = function(a) -- ~ operator
        print("yay ".. a)
        return a
    end
})
print(~ (0))
print(~ (0.3))
print(~ (1))
print(~ (2))
print(~ (2.1))
```

Outputs the following

```
-1
yay 0.3
0.3
-2
-3
yay 2.1
2.1
```

I was expecting

```
yay 0
0
yay 0.3
0.3
yay 1
1
yay 2
2
yay 2.1
2.1
```

It looks like it is not called for integer values.

How do I override the not operator for all numbers?

Comment: According to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html
"Values of all other types share one single metatable per type; that is, there is one single metatable for all numbers"
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments: You can not override everything with a metamethod. Metamethods are fallbacks in Lua. You can only implement operations which were not defined in the Lua language. For example, bitwise operations on numbers having nonzero fractional part were not defined.